# How to compare date part of the datetime field in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Our app has a lease_booking model with a field of lease_date which is a datatime (we use sqlite for development and mysql for production). The app needs to find all the lease_booking on a given date. The code is like:

```
LeaseBooking.where("lease_date == ?", '2012-1-5')
```

The problem is that we can not find any lease_booking on 2012/1/5 because the lease_date is a date+time format. How can the app compare the date part only for a datatime field in rails 3.1?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternately, try this:

```
scope :booking_date, lamda {|d| where('lease_date > ?', Date.parse(d).to_time).where('lease_date < ?', (Date.parse(d) +1).to_time)}
```

And just call

```
LeaseBooking.booking_date('2012-01-05')
```

The `where`-chaining is ugly, but whether or not you can use multiple `?` placeholders, or named variables, to do it in one statement, is highly DB-dependent. ARel is pretty good at turning even ugly chained queries into efficient SQL, though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you'd have to do :

```
LeaseBooking.where("date(lease_date) = ?", '2012-1-5')
```

(with only one `=` sign)

Maybe there is a better answer, because call the "date" function is not really pretty for ActiveRecord! Like Jason Lewis says in the comments, it is DB-specific.

Comment: It's DB-specific, but you'll likely have to coerce the date on the DB side because if you coerce '2012-1-5' into a DateTime or Time, it will only match that date at midnight UTC or local time, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. We only use SQLite and MySQL and both support date(), so it works.

Comment: life saver thanx